# MySQL - Using JSON_SEARCH On Array of Objects

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, object

I'm using [JSON_SEARCH( )](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) to select rows, from a view that supplies JSON data, that match my query. I can find rows that contain a *single* value. For example:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM view
WHERE JSON_SEARCH( column, 'one', '133491626680123392', NULL, '$[*].ID' ) IS NOT NULL;
```

However, instead of searching of an individual value, how would I use the JSON functions to search for *at least one* of multiple values? For example, I'd like to select rows where that column's JSON array has an object that contains the ID `133491626680123392` *or* `277599304154349569`.

What is the best means of accomplishing this? The only method I can think of off of the top of my head - which works - would be to use `JSON_EXTRACT( )` and `REGEXP`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM view
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT( column, '$[*].ID' ) REGEXP CONCAT( '"(', CONCAT_WS( '|', '133491626680123392', '277599304154349569' ), ')"' )

/* Which translates to... */

SELECT *
FROM view
WHERE '["133491626680123392", "228937760390643713"]' REGEXP '"(133491626680123392|277599304154349569)"'
```

Or rather simpler:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM view
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT( column, '$[*].ID' ) REGEXP CONCAT( '"(', CONCAT_WS( '|', ? ), ')"' )
```

Comment: Take a look at the multi-value indexes that was released as part of MySQL 8.0.17